# Why can't I loop through and drop databases?

Tags: python, sql, database

There is a scenario where I want to go through and remove all databases that have specific text in the database name. It always drops one database and then does nothing. How can I fix this?

```
def connect():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password=""
    )
    return mydb


    mydb = connect()

    mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

    mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

    for x in mycursor:
        if ("_tenant_billing" in str(x[0]).lower()):
            print(x[0])
            db = x[0]
            mycursor.execute("DROP DATABASE " + db)
            mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Maybe do databases = mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES").fetchall() Then iterate over that

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine. What  is the error you are encountering?

Comment: @Error_2646 bro it worked!!! lol thank YOU!!!!!!!

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur I wasn't getting any errors - what was happening was it would remove 1 database and then it would just do nothing for an indefinite amount of time

Comment: @TrevorHauter Nice! Posted it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as answer.

Do fetchall() then iterate over that

```
databases = mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES").fetchall()

for database in databases:
    # your stuff
```

Comment: Thank you again! Saved me a lot of headache with this one

Answer (score 0):

Please execute below code and watch how many rows are returned.

def connect():
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
password=""
)
return mydb

```
mydb = connect()

mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

for x in mycursor:
    if ("_tenant_billing" in str(x[0]).lower()):
        print(x[0])
        db = x[0]
```

Comment: @Error_2646 I am not a python expert but I think the problem is calling mycursor.execute() within the cursor. It's creating some kind of infinite loop.